# Saving a large amount of data for later usage

Tags: java, file

I'am quite new to Java and I have programmed an algorithm which downloads data from a webpage. Fetching all the data requires approximately 42 hours. What I want to do is to create some kind of database or some file which can store the data on the hard drive and let me continue my download after my system has been off. The only solution I may conceive is to save it in a text document, and subsequently extract it from the document, when restarting the download. Is this the proper way to go?

Moreover, if relevant, the data is Lists containing strings; along with a name attributed to the list; there is about 2000 lists.

Comment: Save and/or analyze a large amount of complex data == use of a database.

Comment: I would just save the lists as files on my hard drive. You could also zip them on the fly. If it takes 42 hours to download it's probably several hundred GB of data. To continue you just check which lists you already got and then start with the first missing one.

Comment: I would do what ever you feel is simplest.  Using a filesystem or a database may be an option depending on your use case.

Comment: They way I would do it, is save the data into files where the files names are appended by date-time where the last file maybe called file2015030711, so for 42 hours of data you would get 42 files, one for each hour, which means file(year-month-day-hour), then you can always sort the files by name which sorts them in the correct order then you pick the last file

Comment: Thank you for the great answers; saving it as a file does indeed sound the simplest. However,  the data doesn't require much memory. It takes a long time because the program is clicking on buttons and going back and forth between several webpages in order to find the correct data. I presume the total memory of the data would end up at ~2MB. Perhaps I should have been  more clear on that point before... I don't know if your answer changes, now. Once again thank you for the answers!